# How to Index & search the Datetime field in Lucene.NET?

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I don't know how to index and Search the Registred_Date(It contains sql format datetime).I need to search between years or days.where i'm using boolean query for the search.The code below is used for numeric field and ordinary field indexing.

```
       IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(dir, new StandardAnalyzer(),Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
         //ds contains table
        if (ds.Tables[0] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    //Create the Document object
                    Document doc = new Document();

                    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        string check = dc.ToString();
                        if (check.Equals("Experience"))
                        {
                            int n=Convert.ToInt32(dr[dc.ColumnName]);
                            NumericField numericField = new NumericField(dc.ColumnName, Field.Store.YES, true);
                            numericField.SetIntValue(n);
                            doc.Add(numericField);
                        }
                      else if(check.Equals("Registred_Date"))
                        {

                         }
                        else
                        {
                            doc.Add(new Field(dc.ColumnName, dr[dc.ColumnName].ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
                        }
                        //Populate the document with the column name and value from our query
                    }
                    // Write the Document to the catalog
                    indexWriter.AddDocument(doc);
                }
            }
        }
        // Close the writer
        indexWriter.Close();
```

Comment: check this: [Lucene.Net: How can I add a date filter to my search results?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565303/lucene-net-how-can-i-add-a-date-filter-to-my-search-results?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks @Thomas C. G. de Vilhena and Mihai Soloi. I found the solution with your help.

For indexing:

```
DateTime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[dc.ColumnName]);
doc.Add(new Field("Registered_Date", DateTools.DateToString(d1, DateTools.Resolution.SECOND), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

For searching:

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15);
var dateValue = DateTools.DateToString(d1, DateTools.Resolution.MILLISECOND);
var filter = FieldCacheRangeFilter.NewStringRange("Registered_Date",lowerVal: dateValue, includeLower: true,upperVal: null, includeUpper: false);
```

Comment: why not use the SECOND resolution on the indexing? you can have multiple registrations on the same day I assume as you are filtering over the MILLISECOND resolution; both resolutions should be the same imho

Answer (score 1):

If you would store your index as a standard string, for example if you would transform from `2013-07-05 20:00:00` into `20130705200000` you can use the Lucene [RangeQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/TermRangeQuery.html) to search over the ranges.

Sorry I didn't provide any example code, but I am not familiar with the .NET API.